# vbscript error: expected statement (do until)

Tags: vbscript

ok so im trying to do an assignment and i have written this code but it has errors, and i cant see why.

its saying expected statement, and im looking over it and i cant find what the problem is. Would be amazing if someone could shed some light on the error and possibly help me out.

here is the do until statement:

```
Sub btnTransformY_onclick()
    Do Until r = 4 And n = 3
        Do Until m = 1 To 8
            Change(r,c) = (transformationY(r,1) * meh(1, m)) + transformationY(r, 2) * meh(2,m) + TransformationY(r,3) * meh(3,m)  
            m = m + 1
        Next

        c = c + 1
        If c = 8 Then r = r + 1 And c = 1
    Next
End Sub
```

unfortunately this hasnt worked, although it does seem to be the `Do Until m = 1 To 8`
does anyone know if `to` is valid syntax for a do until loop?

Comment: `Do Until m = 1 To 8` is an invalid statement.  You're getting your error when it reaches the To keyword.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your question, even if you now think it was stupid. You had this problem and came here to solve it. Someone else might have the same problem and will be glad to see there is a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reckon you want something on  these lines, except I suspect you want two Next loops for r and n rather than one Do Until.

```
Sub btnTransformY_onclick()
    r = 0
    n = 0

    Do Until r = 4 And n = 3
        For m = 1 To 8
            Change(r,c) = (transformationY(r,1) * meh(1, m)) + transformationY(r, 2) * meh(2,m) + TransformationY(r,3) * meh(3,m)  
            ''m = m + 1
        Next

        c = c + 1
        If c = 8 Then 
            r = r + 1 
            c = 1
            ''Where does n get counted up?
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: that has cleared up the errors thanks...and n's deafault value is 1

Comment: Did you noticed that the step size of m is 2?, since the `For` loop automatically plusplusses m, and `m = m + 1` does this too. I think it is a mistake, but if you really want a stepsize of 2, use `For m = 1 to 8 step 2` this makes your code more maintainable.

Comment: @AutomatedChaos Thanks. I meant to comment out that line as well.

Answer (score 0):

`Next` is for `for` loops, to close a `do` loop use `loop`:

```
do until ..
  ...
loop
```

Also

```
if c = 8 then r = r + 1 and c = 1
```

Is a bitwise comparison (bits of LHS anded with RHS) which is probably not what you want, so instead;

```
if c = 8 then 
   r = r + 1 
   c = 1
end if
```

Comment: And _Then r = r + 1 And c = 1_ too

Comment: unfortunately this hasnt worked, although it does seem to be the Do Until m = 1 To 8 does anyone know if to is valid syntax for a do until loop?

Comment: `To` is only valid with `for m = 1 to 8 ... next` if you want `do until m = 8` you must increment `m` within the loop